Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:8: Android app
Error message:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:8) with 393216 bytes to a Java Buffer with 512 bytes.

I took gpt2 head model from hugging face and converted to tensorflowlite model file and attached the model file in android asset folder and tried to load the gpt2 model in android. here, Input has to be string is pass in generateText function and want to return output as a response.I attached my code and shape of input details above. I'm getting above error while requesting the response from loadModel file.
Input_model details

[{'name': 'serving_default_input_1:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([ 1, 64], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 64], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

LoadModel.kt
class LoadModel(context: Context) {
    private var tflite: Interpreter? = null

    init {
        try {
            tflite = Interpreter(loadModelFile(context, "gpt2_model.tflite"))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun loadModelFile(context: Context, modelName: String): MappedByteBuffer {
        val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(context.assets.openFd(modelName).fileDescriptor)
        val fileChannel = fileInputStream.channel
        val startOffset = context.assets.openFd(modelName).startOffset
        val declaredLength = context.assets.openFd(modelName).declaredLength
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
    }
    
    fun generateText(inputText: String): String {
        // Prepare input tensor
        val inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64 * 4) // 64 tokens * 4 bytes each
        inputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    
        var tokens = tokenize(inputText) // Implement your tokenizer
        if (tokens.size > 64) {
            tokens = Arrays.copyOfRange(tokens, 0, 64) // Truncate to 64 tokens
        }
        for (token in tokens) {
            inputBuffer.putInt(token)
        }
        System.out.println("Number of tokens: " + tokens.size);
    
        val paddingToken = 0
        for (i in tokens.size..63) {
            inputBuffer.putInt(paddingToken)
        }
        // Prepare output tensor
        val outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128 * 4) // Adjust buffer size if needed
        outputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    
        // Run inference
        tflite!!.run(inputBuffer, outputBuffer)
    
        // Decode the output tensor into text (you may need a detokenizer here)
        val outputText = detokenize(outputBuffer) // Implement this method for your tokenizer logic
        return outputText
    }
    
    private fun tokenize(inputText: String): IntArray {
        // Implement your tokenizer logic to convert text into tokens (int array)
        // This is specific to your GPT-2 tokenizer
        return intArrayOf()
    }
    
    private fun detokenize(outputBuffer: ByteBuffer): String {
        // Implement your detokenizer logic to convert tokens (int array) back into text
        return "Generated text"
    }
    
    fun close() {
        if (tflite != null) {
            tflite!!.close() // Properly release TensorFlow Lite interpreter resources
            tflite = null
        }
    }
}

I took gpt2 head model from hugging face and converted to tensorflowlite model file and attached the model file in android asset folder and tried to load the gpt2 model in android. here, Input has to be string is pass in generateText function and want to return output as a response.I attached my code and shape of input details above. I'm getting above error while requesting the response from loadModel file.
